# Падает приложение до полной загрузки Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Голова пухнет дебажить Xamarin когда появляться подобные ошибки в которых я вообще не вижу никаких следов что бы дедуктивно выйти на причину, помогите мне прочитать этот хаос.

```
       **System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
        
        Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7 Поток 0x7 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
        
        "Debugger agent" 03-17 21:29:45.024 E/mono    (17410): Full thread dump:
        
        "Timer-Scheduler" "Finalizer" "ProtocolHandler.ReadThread"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait (object,int) <0x00007>   at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (bool,int,object) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs:85 at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int,bool) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:218 at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:238 at Xamarin.HotReload.HotReloadAgent.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.IDataBridge.ReadMessage () [0x0002f] in D:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin.HotReload.Agent\HotReloadAgent.cs:341   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networkin g.ProtocolHandler.ReadThread () [0x00038] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00014] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:74 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/w orkspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart () [0x00008] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:111 at (wrapper runtime-invoke) object.runtime_invoke_void__this__ (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00067] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0
        
        "ProtocolHandler.ProcessThread"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait (object,int) <0x00007>   at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (bool,int,object) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs:85 at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int,bool) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:218 at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:238 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler/WaitableActionsList.WaitForData () [0x00019] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler.ActionThread (object) [0x00045] in <c37c158 9af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:78 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/cla ss/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (object) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:93 at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0006b] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0
        
        "Thread Pool Worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () <0x00007>   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0002b] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0
        
        "<unnamed thread>"
        
        "<unnamed thread>"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception) <0x00007>   at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException (System.Exception) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/Debugger.cs:125 at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.49 (intptr,intptr) [0x00020] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0   at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.49 (intptr,intptr) [0x00033] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0
        
        "<threadpool thread>" "Thread Pool Worker"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Java.Interop.NativeMethods.java_interop_jnienv_call_static_object_method_a (intptr,intptr&,intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x00007>   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment/StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference,Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo,Jav a.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) [0x00059] in <8b3b636835d84984ba4604c1f57b1983>:0   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers/JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (string,Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue*) [0x0001a] in <8b3b636835d84984ba4604c1f57b1983>:0   at Android.OS.Looper.MyLooper () [0x00011] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0   at Android.Runtime.AndroidEnvironment.GetDefaultSyncContext () [0x00006] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0   at System.AndroidPlatform.GetDefaultSyncContext () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System/AndroidPlatform.cs:57 at System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.GetThreadLocalContext () [0x00005] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs:297 at System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.get_Current () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/ mscorlib/system/threading/synchronizationcontext.cs:272   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.get_IsValidLocationForInlining () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:576 at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunOrScheduleAction (System.Action,bool,System.Threading.Tasks.Task&) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:665 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishContinuations () [0x00052] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3165 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FinishStageThree () [0x0003c] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/Syste m/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2222   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1<System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult>.TrySetResult (System.Threading.Tasks.VoidTaskResult) [0x0004f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Future.cs:422 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task/DelayPromise.Complete () [0x00031] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:5349 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task/<>c.<Delay>b__247_1 (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:5311 at System.Threading.Timer/Scheduler.TimerCB (object) [0x00007] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Timer.cs:369 at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threadi ng.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x00015] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1337 at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00074] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:899 at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs:1261 at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_bool (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0002b] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0
        
        "ProtocolHandler.SendThread"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Threading.Monitor.Monitor_wait (object,int) <0x00007>   at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjWait (bool,int,object) [0x0002f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archiv e-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs:85 at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object,int,bool) [0x0000e] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:218 at System.Threading.Monitor.Wait (object) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs:238 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler/WaitableActionsList.WaitForData () [0x00019] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.TapContract.Networking.ProtocolHandler.ActionThread (object) [0x00045] in <c37c1589af144356b99fb170c5e22242>:0   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context (object) [0x00025] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/thread.cs:78 at System.Threading .ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00071] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:968 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object,bool) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:910 at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext,System.Threading.ContextCallback,object) [0x0002b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/executioncontext.cs:899 at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart (object) [0x0000f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/th read.cs:93   at (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>.runtime_invoke_void__this___object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0006b] in <c72658f647bc485bbfb8c9fcaa790862>:0 03-17 21:30:05.227 I/libc    (17410): Requested dump for tid 17410 (rhelper_v_2.x_0) Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5 Поток 0x5 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0). [HotReload] (2021-03-17 21:31:29.8): ERROR: Caught exception in AgentStatusChangedHandler at 215: Xamarin.HotReload.DebuggerTimeoutException: Failed to Inject Assembly  в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)    в Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject) [HotReload] (2021-03-17 21:31:29.8): INFO: Не удалось запустить Горячую перезагрузку XAML. Если проблема сохраняется, выберите "Справка" -> "Сообщить о проблеме". [HotReload] (2021-03-17 21:31:29.8): INFO: Stopping All Hot Reload sessions due to Failed ... [HotReload] (2021-03-17 21:31:29.8): INFO: (DriverHelper v
        2.0.Android) Stopped Hot Reload session due to Failed ... [HotReload] (2021-03-17 21:31:29.8): INFO: Stopped Hot Reload session.
```

В эмуляторе запускается без проблем, ранее запускалось и на физическом устройстве, сейчас эта ошибка появляться на физическом при старте приложения. Ставил точки остановки тут  `NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);` и приложение все еще работает, после этого ошибка, пробовал комментировать(хотя это бред) все равно ошибка. Пробовал комментировать всё в конструкторе, все равно ошибка. Мои "методы тыка" закончились, прошу помощи.

```
public MainPage()
{
    _api = ServicesCollection.Services.GetService<APIService>();
    InitializeComponent();
    CheckSessionAndServer();
    NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
}
```

```
    **System.NullReferenceException:** 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
    
    Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #5
    Поток 0x5 завершился с кодом 0 (0x0).
    
    "<threadpool thread>"
    "Finalizer"03-17 22:37:10.535 E/mono    ( 1181): Full thread dump:
    
    
    "Thread Pool Worker"
    "Debugger agent"
    "Timer-Scheduler"
    
    "Thread Pool Worker"
    "<unnamed thread>"  at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException_internal (System.Exception) <0x00007>
      at System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Mono_UnhandledException (System.Exception) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.Diagnostics/Debugger.cs:125
      at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.45 (intptr,intptr) [0x00020] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0
      at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.45 (intptr,intptr) [0x00033] in <44e54a86dea24313a2bdb807df77c27a>:0
    03-17 22:37:30.668 I/libc    ( 1181): Requested dump for tid 1181 (rhelper_v_2.x_0)
```

Comment: Перевставьте пожалуйста исключение, только не в блок цитирования, а в блок кода, ограничьте блок с начала ``` none и с конца ```

Comment: @aepot методом тыка выяснил что ошибка была из за подключенного компьютера mac os к студии, так как до этого проверял IOS версию приложения. Но это так случайно получилось, что я отключил студию от компьютера мак, как я должен был понять ошибку по этой куче не понятных логов, дадите совет?

Comment: Выглядит как студия пыталась залить изменения в проекте в отлаживаемое приложение (Hot Reload), но не смогла.

Comment: @aepot в общем один раз приложение запустилось, я ничего не сделал в коде, поюзал функционал, остановил, запускаю снова nullexception только теперь бз кучи дополнительного хлама просто nullreference и все. Это жесть...

Comment: Попробуйте отключить Hot Reload ради эксперимента.

Comment: @aepot отключил, не помогло, дополнил вопрос ошибкой из окна логов

Comment: @aepot на эмуляторе запускается...

Comment: @aepot нашел закономерность, если телефон заблокирован и развернуть из студии на нем приложение то при разблокировке все ок, приложение развернуто и работает, но когда активный экран при старте указанные ошибки. Просто какой то бред.